# How to copy an Excel Worksheet from one Workbook to another

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have been searching online for an answer to this. There are dozens of "solutions", but nothing seems to work right. The application I'm building (using C#) pulls data from a mdb querydef and creates an Excel workbook with two worksheets. That part works perfectly. Now for the part that should be simple: I have a workbook with multiple worksheets (each worksheet will calculate the data differently) I need the code to open the "template" workbook, copy the correct worksheet, and place the copy in the newly created workbook with the other two worksheets. Here's a sample of the code that I feel "should" work:

```
            _Application xlApp;
        Workbook xlTemplateWB;
        Workbook xlTempWB;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new ApplicationClass();
        xlApp.Visible = true;

        //Open Bench Sheet Template
        xlTemplateWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Elmnt.getDBPath() + TEMPLATENAME, 0, true, 5, "", "",
            false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

        //Open temporary workbook
        xlTempWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(XLTempDir + XLTempName, 0, false, 5, true, "", true, 
            XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        //Copy "BOD" Worksheet
        xlTempWB.Worksheets.Copy(xlTemplateWB.Worksheets["BOD"]);
        xlTempWB.Save();

        //Close Workbooks
        xlTempWB.Close(true, missing, missing);
        xlTemplateWB.Close(true, missing, missing);
        xlApp.Quit();

        //Release Objects
        releaseObject(xlTempWB);
        releaseObject(xlTemplateWB);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: It seems from the docs that the Copy parameters specify the destination not the source. So you might want to try something like `sourceWB.Worksheets.Copy(destWB)`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.copy%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Ok. But, xlTemplateWB.Worksheets["BOD"].Copy(xlTempWB); is invalid syntax. I'm assuming I can create an instance of a Worksheet, and then copy it to the new workbook. But, how do I make the new instance of the worksheet to equal the worksheet to copy?

Comment: I tried: ((Worksheet)xlTemplateWB.Worksheets["BOD"]).Copy(xlTempWB); but now I'm recieving this error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Answer (score 2):

Based on my reading of the MSDN documentation, Worksheet.Copy() will only work within a Workbook. Your C# syntax looks correct.

There are a couple of ways to approach this:

1. Duplicate the entire template workbook (using `WorkBook.SaveCopyAs()`) and delete what you don't need.
2. Select the range you want to move and use the clipboard (`Range.Select; Range.Copy; Range.Paste;`) to copy it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I feel like there has to be a way to do this. Maybe several steps? something like: (psuedo code)  Worksheet tempWS = WorksheetToBeCopied; Paste worksheet in the new workbook

Comment: Or, is there a way to create a new workbook from the one worksheet and then I can add the two data worksheets afterwards?

Comment: @DanRicketts - One thing to keep in mind is that Excel object model was first designed with VB5 in mind. It's more procedural than OO and has slowly moved to OO over the years while trying to maintain backwards compatibility. Add the wrinkle that a lot of the .Net objects marshal to COM objects below and things like deep object copies are nearly impossible. Yes, you can create an empty workbook to copy the selected range into, just not as a Worksheet object. Is there a reason why copying the range would not be enough?

Comment: I need the VBA to move with it. Each of the sheets has several hundred lines of code attached to them. Copying the workbook would work, but deleting 23 worksheets to save 1 is horribly inefficient.  I have done this in the past using VB, but this project is in C# (which I’m still learning).

Comment: @DanRicketts - If you were using "modern" VBA, the C# should translate pretty closely. I can't think of a better way to do this in VBA either, though. I think the only way to copy the sheet was to use method #2 above (clipboard copy). If you don't want to copy the entire workbook, you can also copy the individual modules. I would recommend you copy the entire workbook, though, optimizing for the most expensive resource - developer time. This will be a more sustainable solution in the long run and is easy to implement. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. After trying a few more things, I found that the only thing I could get to work was copying the whole workbook and deleting the non-applicable worksheets. I feel that this is very cumbersome, so if anyone finds a better way to do it, I'm all ears. Here's the code that I ended up using:

```
            _Application xlApp;
        Workbook xlTemplateWB;
        Workbook xlTempWB;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new ApplicationClass();
        xlApp.Visible = true;

        //Open Bench Sheet Template
        xlTemplateWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Elmnt.getDBPath() + TEMPLATENAME, 0, true, 5, "", "",
            false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

        //Save As a temporary workbook
        xlTemplateWB.SaveAs(XLTempDir + XLTempName);
        xlTemplateWB.Close(true, missing, missing);
        releaseObject(xlTemplateWB);

        //Open temporary workbook
        xlTempWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(XLTempDir + XLTempName, 0, false, 5, true, "", true,
            XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        //Remove non-applicable worksheets
        for (int i = xlTempWB.Sheets.Count; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (((Worksheet)xlTempWB.Sheets[i]).Name != bchSheet)
            {
                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                ((Worksheet)xlTempWB.Sheets[i]).Delete();
                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
            }
        }
        xlTempWB.Save();

        //Close Workbooks
        xlTempWB.Close(true, missing, missing);
        xlApp.Quit();

        //Release Objects
        releaseObject(xlTempWB);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
```